# cloudfront Cache-Control headers are different than origin headers

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm seeing a situation where requests through Cloudfront have a different Cache-Control than my origin. I have Object Caching set to "Use Origin Cache Headers" and (I don't think this is relevant) Compress Objects Automatically set to "No"

I've found that if I change Object Caching to "Customize" and change the value around that does in fact change the headers returned from the CDN.  That's okay and all... but I'm curious to know why with my existing settings this header isn't being passed through.

Thanks!

Compressed Request from Origin - shows Cache-Control of '31536000'

```
(05:34 PM) jsharpe@mbp:~ curl -I https://staging.testing.com/assets/application-0d5691ba401c3f5a305fda52745a831376545a605a6c16e50fc838fdaa567e57.css --compressed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 21:34:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 05:05:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
Content-Length: 33563
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Compressed Request from CDN - shows Cache-Control of '86400'

```
(05:34 PM) jsharpe@mbp:~ curl -I https://staging-cdn.testing.com/assets/application-0d5691ba401c3f5a305fda52745a831376545a605a6c16e50fc838fdaa567e57.css --compressed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 33563
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Cowboy
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 05:07:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 05:05:25 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Content-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 7d327ef7e21429ba6a44eb6374c976f3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Age: 59233
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: TEqKbQ5ZYySY7m8rDft_MAlygEiam6gYvzrXBpS7D2DrBNbVUZ1y3Q==
```

Comment: This isn't consistent with the expected behavior *at all.*  I will try to replicate this behavior...

Comment: I have not been able to duplicate this so far.  86400 is the default value for Default TTL.  Is that the value that's matching?  Can you change that setting to, let's say, 28800 and get a `max-age=28800` response from CloudFront? (!?)  Or is it min or max that you're setting to 86400?  Is it possible that variations in the curl request vs what CloudFront actually sends (it does modify requests, not all headers are passed through) could actually be triggering a different `Cache-Control` response from the origin itself?

Comment: In order to change Default TTL you have to set Object Caching to Customize - which by definition overwrites the headers coming from the origin.  Yes - that 'works' but per my original question is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: *"set Object Caching to Customize - which by definition overwrites the headers coming from the origin."*  By definition... no, it doesn't.  "Customize" only changes CloudFront's internal expiration timers.  The `Cache-Control` headers are still passed through, unchanged.  You are claiming *"if I change Object Caching to "Customize" and change the value around that does in fact change the headers returned from the CDN"* and I am asking you which value you are changing that results in this behavior, because I cannot duplicate it.  `Cache-Control` is always unchanged.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misinterpreted that - I appreciate the clarification.  I'd like to get away from using the "Customize" option since my original question is concerned about having "Use Origin Cache Headers" set.

Comment: Okay, *now* I believe I understand what you are saying.  I thought your issue was that "Use Origin Cache Headers" worked as expected but customizing the settings didn't.  CloudFront should never modify the `Cache-Control` response header from the origin.  Obviously, a Lambda@Edge Response trigger could do that, but if you had a trigger then I'd assume you put it there and expected the behavior. Do a cache invalidation for this object (or the whole distribution) and retest. The implication is that your origin varies its responses or something at the origin has changed.

Comment: Or... I'm guessing based on `Via: vegur` that the origin is Heroku, so perhaps *they* have some inconsistent behavior?

Comment: As in they respond differently to requests coming from cloudfront than they do otherwise?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  As I mentioned, CloudFront strips a majority of the request headers, and rewrites others, because this is necessary for correct cache behavior.  For just one example, by default it [sets the `User-Agent` to `Amazon CloudFront`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-user-agent-header).  Essentially anything CloudFront forwards to the origin, it assumes must be identical on subsequent requests in order for its cached response to be valid. (Difficult to explain briefly, this design is correct.)